# character class in regular expression vs shorthand

Tags: javascript, regex

The javscript [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-character-set) on regexp states:

> \w Matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]

Taking that into consideration, why do I see some code in this fashion: `[\w]`. Is this just bad habits in beiong verbose? JavaScript clearly states that `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Any references/cites (with links) to official documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: You can even see people writing something like `[x]` or `a|b|c`. Regexp syntax is tricky and not everyone gets it right.

Comment: Yup, just a Bad Habit -- hypercompleteness, or possibly [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Using `[\w]` doesn't make sense at all IMO. The brackets are redundant since it's the same as `\w`. Some people tend to use character classes instead of escaping, for example `[.]` instead of `\.` since the dot loses it's meaning in a character class. This behaviour is more about readability and style. On a side note, sometimes you want to exclude the underscore from `\w`. There is a trick ! Use the inverse of it `\W` (uppercase), add it to a negated character class `[^\W]` and add the underscore `[^\W_]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `\w` and `[\w]` function the same. It's a matter of "style" / preference.
However, sometimes it's necessary to use `\w` in a character class, in cases like this:

```
[\w ]* --> "abcd efg hijk" // Matches the whole line
\w*    --> "abcd efg hijk" // Matches "abcd"
```

[Example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5Cw%2a%0A%5B%5Cw%20%5D%2a&input=abcd%20efg%20hijk%0Aabcd%20efg%20hijk)

Answer (score 1):

Every tool has somewhat of a different interpretation of regular expression use. In this case they both reference the same. Keep in mind character classes don't nest in some flavors, therefore you would need to use POSIX-style character classes `[[:alnum:]_]` or `\w` alone.

But yes, here they are the same and IMO just bad habit of regular expression use.